# Deploying a zip file with CloudFoundry java client library

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I am trying to get a cloud foundry app deployed using the cf-java-client (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client).  I can push a .jar file from a /tmp directory (applicationPath below). It works.

```
    return ops.applications()
        .push(PushApplicationRequest.builder()
            .name(name)
            .application(applicationPath)
            .buildpack(buildPack)
            .diskQuota(diskQuota)
            .memory(memory)
            .stagingTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .noStart(true)
            .build());
```

However, when trying to deploy a .zip file (as in a zipped node.js app), it doesn't work.

I've seen an example of uploading an application zip file using the client (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-cloudappswithjava/) but I would think that the the CloudFoundryOperations push command would work equally well with both a .zip and a .jar since it is - to my understanding - performing any task you might do with the cli. And I can push a .zip file (the same zip file) with cf push {zip file}.

Anyone ever done this with a zip and been successful? Thanks.